# ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line

Tags: angularjs, charts

Hello I am trying to crate Multi Axis Line chart in Angular js. And I got this error;

> ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to
> render chart line

Here is the Html codes;

```
 <div style="display: block;">
          <div class="chart-wrapper">
            <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="chartData.datasets"
            [labels]="chartData.labels"
            [legend]="true"
            [chartType]="'line'" id="zoneWiseReport"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the js one is

```
  chartData : any{};
    this.homeService.getZoneSalesWise(fromDate,toDate,this.selectedZones).subscribe(result=>{
            console.log(result,'zoneSales')
              if(result !== null){  
               for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                  this.chartData = {
                    labels: result[i].journeyDate,
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        label: 'Dataset 1',
                        data: result[i].sales,
                        yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: 'red'
                      },
                    ]
                  }
    
               return this.chartData;
             
              }        
       } })
      }
```

Thank you in advance for your help